# Monitor HDMI connection not working

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, external-display

When I first bought my computer/monitor a few years ago, I could never get the HDMI connection to work, so I just used a DVI. Well I just bought a new monitor and the HDMI connection still doesn't work.

I tried to update my graphics card driver. Which I did successfully. I have a Nvidia Geforce GT 740. I also tried unplugging/plugging back in the HDMI cord several times.

Nothing happens when the HDMI cord is plugged in. The signal simply isn't sending over to my monitor.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try or ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you try a different HDMI cable?

Comment: Yes, I tried a different cable. The same thing happened with my old monitor years ago and I tried three cables then.